# Wirecloud FIWARE NGSI Proxy

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I need NGSI proxy over http. Is there any instance of NGSI Proxy over http?

Alternatively, Is it possible to install NGSI Proxy on my own server?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have restored the `ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` machine, this machine supports both protocols `http` and `https`.

Anyway, you can create your own `ngsi-proxy` instance downloading it from [github](https://github.com/conwetlab/ngsijs/tree/master/ngsi-proxy).